# Ridge regression coefficients that are larger than OLS coefficients or that change sign depending on $\lambda$

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients, ridge-regression

When running ridge regression, how do you interpret coefficients that end up larger than their corresponding coefficients under least squares (for certain values of $\lambda$)?  Isn't ridge regression supposed to monotonically shrink coefficients?

On a related note, how does one interpret a coefficient whose sign changes during ridge regression (i.e., the ridge trace crosses from negative to positive on a ridge trace plot)?

Comment: Ridge regression only monotonically shrinks coefficients in the case of an orthogonal design matrix.  In the presence of correlations, its impossible to say anything of that generality.

Answer (score 5):

As $\lambda$ increases from zero the contribution of various coefficients changes to suit the optimization, allowing both value increases and sign changes.  Have a look at Ryan Tibshirani's ridge regression charts (PDF) [illustrating both of your questions (charts 17, 19).](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/datamining/lectures/16-modr1.pdf)